# Could you simplify "status parameters" in this passage, please

Tags: word-meaning

> Likewise, the evolutionary approach predicts that the biological and anatomical differences between men and women will result in different preferences for partner selection. For example, human biology dictates that women need help and protection during pregnancy, and that their fertility is time-limited. Therefore, it makes sense that men who can provide protection will be deemed attractive to women, and that young—and hence fertile—women will be attractive to men. Indeed, studies show that when it comes to long-term relationships, women overall emphasize the importance of **status parameters** while men find female youth highly attractive.

Source: http://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/insight-therapy/201412/laws-attraction-how-do-we-select-life-partner

I have my doubts as to whether it is reffering to the wealth and powers a man might have, also whether it is reffering to marital status.

Answer (score 1):

In that context, **status parameters** means "aspects of social status, such as wealth, power, rank, responsibility, and respect".

The phrase **status parameters** has no standard meaning in English, and the writing is somewhat unclear for placing it there with so little explanation. The writer is intending to echo the well-known phrase [**social status**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_status), not **marital status**.

Answer (score 0):

IMO,

In **this context,** it seems that the author is talking about *financial and its related* status that make a man capable enough to provide her security/safety. That's because the paragraph is talking about what women like and get attracted toward. She needs protection and security and thus, a man who can provide this all would be her choice.

On the other hand, I don't find *marital status* as *status* in this context. For a long term relationship, how would *marital status* serve the purpose?